# Order of statement execution

Tags: mdx, business-intelligence, olap, olap-cube

Suppose I run a `SUM` function on some set inside a `WITH MEMBER` construct. In the `WHERE` clause I limit, narrow down the size of the set (by date, for example). Would calculations in `WITH MEMBER` run for the entire set, or does the interpreter know about the narrowing down ahead of time and so would not waste CPU cycles doing all the calculations for an entire set?

```
WITH MEMBER Measures.[Summed] AS   
   SUM(
        {[Sample].[Sample ID].[Sample ID]}, 
        [Measures].[Value]
   )  

SELECT {[Measures].[Value], Measures.[Summed]} ON 0
FROM [A Cube]
WHERE([Dim Date].[ymd].[Date Name].&[01 Apr 2016]
```

The query will display results for April 1, 2016. But would it run the calculations for all dates before doing so? Or would it be efficient?

Comment: lots of efficiencies are built in - in the same way that any interpreter of a declarative language attempts to find the best way of running a script.

Comment: so, in this case, it would run calculations on a limited set, saving CPU cycles?

Comment: it will do calculations within the context of the script

Comment: Thank you! What exactly do you mean by "context of the script"? How does it work with calculated members, which can be defined for a cube? For those, one supplies an MDX expression, but, as far as I understand, there is no way to filter anything at that point. Users of the cube do the filtering in Excel themselves. What would be the order in that case? Calculations on everything, or on a limited set?

Comment: "context" is defined by the WHERE clause and the SELECT clause